# How can I find a GitHub project from my podfile?

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I have an iOS application.

I'm using CocoaPods.

I have a `podfile` with all my pods names.

I want to check changes made on one of the pods in GitHub, but I don't know how to get to my projects page.

How can I find the exact project from my `podfile` in GitHub?

For example -

One of the pods is `GoogleAnalytics`, searching "GoogleAnalytics" on GitHub will find multiple results with this exact name written by different developers.

[image]

[image]

How can I find the `GoogleAnalytics` from my `podfile`?

Writing the pod name on CocoaPods will get you to the specs but will not get you to the projects GitHub page.

Comment: Going into the framework files should have a header file which has information relating to the specifics. More so, search for the pod on https://cocoapods.org/ to get the exact response.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJ , Sometimes there is a readme file on the pod folder, in it i found some good clues to find the project on github. unfortunately this is only the case in 20% of the pods.

Comment: If you’re using the offical google analytics; try and find the link via their documentation. Probably your best bet.

Comment: It was just an example :) , I have about 20 pods...

Answer (score 2):

See the [source line in the podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/4/9/c/GoogleAnalytics/3.17.0/GoogleAnalytics.podspec.json#L16).

The GoogleAnalytics pod is a binary framework only and does not make its source available on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics was just an example, but after [@Paul Beusterien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556617/paul-beusterien) answer I understood that some companies sources may not be available on CocoaPods search, that made me search for the smaller independent developer pods, there I have found links to GitHub.

So the answer - if it helps anyone -

Search on [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) for the links to GitHub, if you can't find it, it's probably big enough to find on google or on that dependency's website.